# Time series proportion/share modelling issue

Tags: time-series, modeling, proportion, percentage, beta-regression

I want to model **import share** (one commodity product in country) as dependent variable from **local price premium** (local price minus import price) and **seasonality factor** (0 or 1). Model is used to make an inference for predition of import share in the future.

The intuition is:

- when local price is too high compared to import alternative, costumers start buying more import product
- and if local price is too low compared to import althernative - volume of import share is close to zero.
  There is natural lag between cause and effect -  usually one month, and effect usually lasts for two months. For example if local price premium is high in March, import share increases in April-May. Ther is also natural seasonality -  in autumn/winter costumers are less likely to switch to import because demand is weak.

Data is processed to monthly based (47 observations).
Each observation is:

- Price premium with one month lag
- Import share for two months (current and 1 month forward)
- Seasonality factor

**Import share** is continous (strictly between 0 and 1), 90% of values are between 0 and 0.1. There is auto corellation. Non stationary.

**Price premium** is continous, can be both negative and positive, measured as percentage. There is auto corellation. Non stationary.

I have read some articles that imply that beta regression should be used to model share/proportion, but I have time series data. Variables are non stationary and I am not sure if I can straitforward employ beta regression here to make statistically significan inference.

I am not sure I can use cointegration because it does nog guaranty dependent variable to stay in (0,1) boundary.

I also read some suggestions - when using beta regression for time series to add to model lags of dependent and explanatory variables and ensure that residuals do not corellate.

Can anybody suggest a right approach for my case? I can share csv file if needed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Roman this is really interesting, I was wondering if you found an answer to this? And if you did could you share the best approach you found please?